# Spring and logging properties file

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons-logging

I'm trying to use Spring. A dependency of Spring is

So I have added `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` to my build path. This all works fine. And I get stuff like this:

```
Feb 28, 2013 2:40:39 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@c63a8af: startup date [Thu Feb 28 14:40:39 GMT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
```

This is all great but I don't want this printed to my standard out, I would prefer it to be sent to a file.

DirectoryStructure:

```
project
  src
    com.myproject.classes
    myspring.xml
    log4j.properties
  test
    com.myproject.classes
  logs
    myproject.log
```

So I would like to get all logs redirected from the standard out to the log file instead. Is this possible with Spring?

I've used the properties file from here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/logging_with_log4j.htm,
where I got my Spring example from. But this doesn't seem to make any difference. I've added some rubbish in there too to see if any exceptions get thrown, but nothing. I've tried moving the file around to different directories, but it still doesn't work.

Here it is:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/myproject.log

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add log4j.jar and log4j.properties too in your classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this configuration : http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?94000-org-springframework-util-Log4jConfigurer-is-overriding-my-log4j-xml

Read the configuration class: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.x/api/org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer.html

For source code of Log Configuration - go through this :

http://git.springsource.org/sandbox/cbeams/blobs/bb96df1ed8e3720f33353824b108104027289e5c/org.springframework.core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer.java